# Security of a web facing cron

Tags: php, security, web, cron

Right now I have a cron job that is used for cleaning a database used by a web application. This can't be done in SQL as I need to reference AWS which I am unable to do with SQL or PL/SQL. So I have a cron job that runs once a week to do the cleaning.

As it stands the function call for the cron is /usr/big/wget www.webiste.com/cron/cronjob.php

The script checks for an environment variable we a have set on our server as was suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5146772/3245442 to prevent the script being able to be ran publicly.

I'm wondering how secure this implementation actually is, and if I would be better security wise having a folder outside of the /var/www directory with python scripts for the cron to call, or if that would be overkill.

Comment: If users have no need to access the file, it should not be reachable. That's a solid baseline to work from.

Comment: how about you put it here: `/usr/big/cronjob.php` or anywhere not accessible by users